# Get Values from JSON within Array using condition in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, unirest

I am using Unirest, to get all id's from an end point,
My Array is like this:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2022-04-05",
        "timeIn": "2022-04-05 07:00:00",
        "timeOut": "2022-04-05 14:00:00",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-05 08:32:59",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-06 13:42:23",
        "deletedAt": "2022-04-06 13:42:23",
        "id": 3984193,
        "userId": 42602,
        "storeId": 1845,
        "positionId": 8161,
        "clockInIP": null,
        "clockOutIP": null,
        "isDeleted": 1,
        "timeInEdited": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "2022-04-04",
        "timeIn": "2022-04-04 07:00:00",
        "timeOut": "2022-04-04 14:00:00",
        "createdAt": "2022-04-06 13:36:03",
        "updatedAt": "2022-04-06 13:36:03",
        "deletedAt": null,
        "id": 3984196,
        "userId": 42602,
        "storeId": 1845,
        "positionId": 8161,
        "clockInIP": null,
        "clockOutIP": null,
        "isDeleted": 0,
        "timeInEdited": 1
    }
]
```

Now I want to get all `id's` , where `isDeleted` is 0, I am using a logic, which will get `id's` but , I need to get `id's` using this condition using Java.

```
            JSONArray jArray = bodyResponse.getBody().getArray();
            int len = jArray.length();
            for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
                ids.add((Integer) json.get("id"));
}
```

Can someone help me out on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your for Loop like this :-

```
for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
    JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
    if(json.getInt("isDeleted") == 0 ){
        ids.add((Integer) json.get("id"));
    }
 }
```